# java.lang.VerfyError: send e-mail in Android 11

Tags: android, sendmail, android-11

I wrote a method to send an email from my app.
This method works perfectly in all versions of Android, except in Andorid 11.
This is my implementations in Grandle:

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
```

This is my method that sends the e-mail:

```
public static boolean send(String oggetto, String testo, String[] dests) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        }
    });
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    final boolean[] send = new boolean[1];
    final boolean[] loading = {false};
    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USERNAME));
        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[dests.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dests.length; i++)
        {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(dests[i]);
        }
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
        message.setSubject(oggetto);
        message.setText(testo);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Transport.send(message);
                    loading[0] = true;
                    send[0] = true;
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    loading[0] = true;
                    send[0] = false;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        return false;
    }
    while (!loading[0]) {}
    return send[0];
}
```

This is the log error in Android 11:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain that attempts to sub-type erroneous class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base
```

Comment: Are you using proguard?  This sounds like a possible obfuscation issue.

Comment: No, I am not using it.